# set remaining height to view at runtime

Tags: android, height, layoutparams

I am writing an application where need to assign rest of screen space to view.

```
<LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtView_1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtView_2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Test Text" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

and to set runtime I am using following:

```
private void process() {
        DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);

        int txtView1Height = txtView_1.getHeight();

        LayoutParams layoutParams = (LayoutParams) txtView_2.getLayoutParams();

        layoutParams = new LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                (metrics.heightPixels - txtView1Height));

        txtView_2.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    }
```

But here it's taking not exact same remaining height..since textview sting not placing in center(this is how I simply check)...it might be mistaken to set height in pixel.

Any suggestion here?

Comment: No need to do that in code. Just assign `match_parent` to txtView_2's height. It will fill **the remaining space**.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `weight` xml parameter

```
<TextView
android:id="@+id/txtView_2"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:layout_weight="1.0"
android:gravity="center"
android:text="Test Text" />
```

or in your case simple set height to `match_parent`

```
android:layout_height=match_parent
```

To check even more simpler set gravity to `bottom`. If you still want to do this programmatically dont use `DisplayMetrics` to get height (Action Bar and Software Buttons are also a part of display) use your root `LinearLayout` height. Also check if `txtView1Height` is not `0` (maybe `view` was not drawed at the moment of calculation)